# Error "Error: stray character" when using C++11

Tags: c++, boost, c++11, g++, boost-thread

I'm running into a strange issue when I try to compile the following simple C++11 code on my machine:

```
#include <boost/thread/thread.hpp>
```

It compiles fine with `g++ foo.cpp -o foo but chokes on g++ -c -std=c++11 foo.cpp -o foo` with the following error:

```
In file included from /usr/local/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin11.4.0/4.7.1/../../../../include/c++/4.7.1/functional:56:0,
             from /usr/local/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin11.4.0/4.7.1/../../../../include/c++/4.7.1/memory:81,
             from /usr/local/include/boost/config/no_tr1/memory.hpp:21,
             from /usr/local/include/boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp:27,
             from /usr/local/include/boost/shared_ptr.hpp:17,
             from /usr/local/include/boost/thread/pthread/thread_data.hpp:10,
             from /usr/local/include/boost/thread/thread.hpp:17,
             from foo.cpp:1:
./tuple:1:1: error: stray ‘\317’ in program
./tuple:1:1: error: stray ‘\372’ in program
./tuple:1:1: error: stray ‘\355’ in program
./tuple:1:1: error: stray ‘\376’ in program
... Additional lines omitted
```

I'm at a loss. Especially since I've been able to compile other programs against C++11 without any issue. Any ideas?

I'm running [OS X v10.7.4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mac_OS_X_Lion) (Lion) and GCC 4.7.1.

Comment: Hmm, odd. What version of Boost? Have you opened tuple to see what characters it starts with (perhaps a BOM)?

Comment: Can you confirm which `tuple` file it uses, and verify it's the right one? If all else fails, running g++ under `strace` will show which file it actually found ...

Comment: @Useless: No need for `strace`; `gcc -H` will print the path of all headers, in the (recursive) order that they're included.

Comment: @MSalters: No need for `-H` either, you have the path of the file in the error message: `./tuple`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because you have a file in your current directory named `tuple` that is included instead of the standard `tuple` header. Probably because of some `-I.` in the compilation line.

The strays characters in the error messages are simply the first bytes of the file not in the allowed character set, in octal.